# Error with mixins in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm just learning Scala, and I have these three files:

```
  abstract class Animal() {
    name
    sound
}



 class Dog(n : String) extends Animal {
    name = n
    val sound = "Boof"
}

trait Speaking extends Animal {
    def speak(n : String, s : Sound) : String = {
        println(s + "! I'm " + n + "!")
    }
}
```

In my main method, I have the following code:

```
d = new Dog("Maddie") with Speaking
println(d.speak)
```

When I run this code, I get error: not found: value d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `val` before `d` if you haven't declared it before.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be something like this:

```
abstract class Animal() {
  def name: String // You need a type(String) and a qualifier(def)
  def sound: String // the same
}

class Dog(n : String) extends Animal {
  // Type is not obligatory here, as it is inherited from Animal. 
  // But you still need a qualifier(val)
  val name = n 
  val sound = "Boof"
}

trait Speaking extends Animal {
  // This method doesn't need those params,
  // since this trait extends Animal, 
  // so it has access to name and sound defined there.
  def speak: String = {
    sound + "! I'm " + name + "!"
  }
}
```

Your main method remains the same.